# Use DATABASE_URL by default with Sinatra/Sequel extension

Tags: ruby, sinatra, sequel

The [README for sinatra/sequel](https://github.com/rtomayko/sinatra-sequel/blob/master/README.md) states that the `set :database` statement can be omitted and it will use the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable by default. Looking at the source, this appears to be true. However, omitting this line causes the following error when it tries to load my model definitions:

```
.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sequel-4.25.0/lib/sequel/model/base.rb:226:
in `db': No database associated with Sequel::Model: have you called Sequel.connect 
or Sequel::Model.db= ? (Sequel::Error)
```

I realize I'm being a bit pedantic by wanting to omit this line (and not have to write `:set database, ENV['DATABASE_URL']`) but for the sake of learning is there a way to invoke the default behavior of this module? I asked the question [over here](https://github.com/rtomayko/sinatra-sequel/issues/13) as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please note that the last commit in this project was in January 2013, you're likely to face funny problems because both Sinatra and Sequel evolved since then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I answered in the linked GitHub issue, the best way to do it is to simply call `database` from the `configure` block, and this will invoke the default logic.

```
configure do
  abort 'Unable to establish database connection' unless database
end
```